dotnet restore not equivalent to VS 2022 (restore option in context menu for solution)
I have a solution with many many sub projects (104), and we are using two sources for nuget packages, one in Azure Devops Artifacts and the other is nuget.org.
We have in the first one, packages for a old version of Orchard Core, but the developer at the moment uploaded these packages with a version number 2.0.0 (in 2019). And then come the problem that Orchard Core team added recently produced a version 2.0.0 but not the same than our version.
the problem is that our version is for .NetCore 2.2 and the one from the Orchard Core Team is for .Net8.
in any case it does not have to be a problem because, we use in the Nuget.config the 2 packages sources and the packagesourcemapping options for specifically the packages Orchard Core to be sure that the version used is from our source.
Using Visual studio 2022 to restore nuget packages work fine but the problem is that we use also a Devops Pipeline that included command line Dotnet Restore.
On my computer, i installed the SDK 2.2 and SDK 8. In the powershell console, the command dotnet restore :
dotnet restore .\Tyndareus\Tyndareus.sln --configfile .\Tyndareus\NuGet.config --force-evaluate
does not seems to work with errors : error NU1202: Package OrchardCore.ContentManagement 2.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package OrchardCore.ContentManagement 2.0.0 supports: net80
the dotnet restore command does not respect the nuget.config mentions packagesourcemapping because it take the wrong version from nuget.org (compatible only with .Net8):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="extern" value="https://lagardere-tr-fr.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/extern/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
  <packageSourceMapping>
    <packageSource key="extern">
      <package pattern="OrchardCore*" />
      <package pattern="TheAdmin*" />
      <package pattern="TheTheme*" />
      <package pattern="TheAgencyTheme*" />
      <package pattern="TheBlogTheme*" />
      <package pattern="TheComingSoonTheme*" />
      <package pattern="SafeMode" />
    </packageSource>
    <packageSource key="nuget">
      <package pattern="*" />
    </packageSource>
  </packageSourceMapping>  
</configuration>

taking the package from nuget.org and not from our devops.
it is supposed to work same between VS restore and dotnet restore.
why the packagesourcemapping is not respected ? packagesourcemapping is supported in .net 2.2 ?

They both defintely behave differently as documented here. A wild guess: maybe the mapping of * to nuget is the problem, because it overrides all other mappings? Try removing it and maybe both tools will pick nuget for all unmapped packages.

the mapping * for nuget's source package mapping is not the problem, i did try with named packages and i have the same problem.

Firstly, you need to seperate the build tools (.NET SDK) from the runtime (.NET). I know the naming is confusing, but I don't have the power to change it. It is what it is.
You can build projects using a target framework less than or equal to the major version of the SDK you're using, as you appear to know about from your local machine development. So, the .NET 8 SDK can build projects targeting net8.0, net 7.0, net 6.0, etc.  So, just because you're building a project targeting netcoreapp2.2 doesn't mean you need to install the .NET Core 2.2 SDK. You can have just the .NET 8 SDK installed, but you'd need to install the .NET Core 2.2 runtime to run it (the runtime can be installed separately from the SDK, and is very much recommended for servers)
Next, if you look at NuGet's docs on package source mapping, it clearly states that it's available starting from the .NET 6.0.100 SDK. So no, it's not supported by the .NET Core 2.2 SDK (although you wrote .NET 2.2, and without the SDK part it means runtime, and NuGet doesn't ship in the runtime, only the SDK).
Although Package Source Mapping is a tool that can help you here, this is also a good demonstration that when forking software, the person responsible should also change the name to avoid risks like this (the real software releasing the same version) from affecting you.
Finally, the .NET Core 2.2 runtime went out of support in 2019. Microsoft doesn't report CVEs on out of support software, so don't let the lack of CVEs for this old version give you a false sense of security. Who knows how many CVEs for .NET Core 3.0 or above also apply to 2.2, but were not reported. There are plenty of examples of companies who were hacked because they didn't keep their software up to date. The most famous example was probably Equifax back in 2017. If your service is internet facing, I strongly encourage you to talk to your management chain about funding the effort to update to supported versions of .NET. In fact, even if your service is not internet facing you should still do it, because if an attacker finds another way into your company's network, then your .NET Core 2.2 service could become a pivot point for the attacker to gain access to more of the network.
